# Calculating months between 2 dates, then calculating days in each month

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to create a graph by getting the start and end date from the user. I need to count the number of months between the dates, then for each month calculate the number of days and get the name of the month as well.

I've got the number of months between the 2 dates but can't seem to translate the remaining into code. I have a class called MonthRange

```
public class MonthRange
{
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }

    public string monthName { get; set; }

    public MonthRange() {
    }

    public MonthRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string monthName) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.monthName = monthName;
    }
}
```

And my method:

```
private List<MonthRange> GetRangeOfMonthsBetweenDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {

     List<MonthRange> result = new List<MonthRange>();
     int months = (endDate.Year - startDate.Year)*12 + endDate.Month - startDate.month;

foreach(var m in months){
     //get the start and end date of that month with the name and add it to the result list.
}

}
```

The kicker is that if the startDate is midway through the month, then that is what should be saved in the result list, likewise if the endDate is midway of the month, that is what should be saved. I'm a bit lost and would appreciate any help.

Edit: So this is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to create a graph that plots the number of times a person has had food in a given time range.

Edit 2: So i ended up going this way:

```
 private List<MonthRange> GetRangeOfMonthsBetweenDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {

        List<MonthRange> result = new List<MonthRange>();

        DateTime holder = startDate;

        var months = (endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12 + endDate.Month - startDate.Month;


        for (int i = 0; i <= months; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                result.Add(new MonthRange(startDate, CalculateStartOfMonth(endDate), startDate.ToString("MMM")));
            }
            else if (i == months)
            {
                result.Add(new MonthRange(CalculateEndOfMonth(startDate), endDate, endDate.ToString("MMM")));
            }
            else {
                DateTime middleMonth = holder.AddMonths(1);
                result.Add(new MonthRange(CalculateStartOfMonth(middleMonth), CalculateEndOfMonth(middleMonth), middleMonth.ToString("MMM")));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private DateTime CalculateStartOfMonth(DateTime endDate) {
        var startOfMonth = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1);
        return startOfMonth;
    }

    private DateTime CalculateEndOfMonth(DateTime startDate)
    {
        var endOfMonth = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(startDate.Year, startDate.Month));
        return endOfMonth;
    }
```

Comment: any example input and output that you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure what you've got is even correct? Do you really want to return `1` as the count of months, when you input e.g. `Dec 31 2016 23:59` and `Jan 1 2017 00:01` as your start and end dates, respectively? The rest of your description is similarly vague. You need to start by writing a _precise_, _unambiguous_ specification detailing exactly what computation you actually want. With that, the code will be easy to write. Without it, you could wander in circles for weeks trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Mark Eg: If the user enters startDate as 16/05/2017 and endDate as 24/07/2017. Then the number of months should be 3 and for the first month, the start date would be the 16th, 2nd month would be whole and 3rd month would end on the 24th. Does that make sense?

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, It would count as a different month as the graph will plot items based on the month it belongs to.

Comment: What you want to do is very odd and perhaps it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to track days instead of months and then, when you display it, visually group the days that belong to the same month? I'd expect most people eat once a day in any period that you come up with (well, at least the ones who use a computer to track it, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this is not an answer to the question but a suggestion for a different approach. Since the question is about charting number of meals for a person over a period, I think the natural way to approach this (at least for representing the data) is to do it by day, not by month. (Visually, the data may have to be represented by month but it's much easier to first organize the data by days and then render it by month.)

Since the question is rather vague, I made some assumptions about the data. This class could be used to store information about a single day.

```
class DayEntry
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfMeals { get; set; }
}
```

The following function creates a list of `DayEntry` objects, initialized for each day in the date range:

```
List<DayEntry> CreateDayEntries(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
{
    var dateDiff = dateEnd - dateStart;
    var dayCount = (int) Math.Ceiling(dateDiff.TotalDays) + 1;
    var dayRange = new List<DayEntry>(dayCount);

    for (var i = 0; i < dayCount; i++)
    {
        var date = dateStart.AddDays(i);
        var dayEntry = new DayEntry
        {
            Date = date,
            NumberOfMeals = 0, // TODO
            MonthName = date.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) 
        };

        dayRange.Add(dayEntry);
    }

    return (dayRange);
}
```

When the data is prepared for the given date range, it can then be shown in a UI, grouped by month - since each day entry has its own date (with the name of the month it belongs to) and are in order in the list, it's easy to iterate through them and create the UI output.

Comment: this is what i was kinda looking for. I used your answer but made a few changes on how to calculate dates, name etc. Adding my answer to the post :)

Comment: @bluebrigade23 No problem, I'm glad if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `MonthRange` structure, try this:

```
private IEnumerable<MonthRange> GetRangeOfMonthsBetweenDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {        
    var start = startDate;  
    while(start<endDate) {
        var end = start.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-start.Day);           
        yield return new MonthRange(start, end < endDate ? end : endDate, start.ToString("MMMM"));

        start = end.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

For example:

```
var start = new DateTime(2017,5,16);
var end = new DateTime(2017,7,24);

foreach(var m in GetRangeOfMonthsBetweenDates(start, end)) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:dd/MM/yyyy}-{2:dd/MM/yyyy}", m.monthName, m.startDate, m.endDate);
}
```

Should print:

```
May: 16/05/2017-31/05/2017
June: 01/06/2017-30/06/2017
July: 01/07/2017-24/07/2017
```

Comment: This solution works good but has a little bug on line `while(start<endDate) {` because it should be `while(start<=endDate) {`. The original code fails with ranges 31/01/21 - 01/02/21, but the fixed one works good. P.S: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Another bug into the code, when the date range involves months with different number of total days. For example, if you try into the code the date range `31/05/21 - 10/06/21`, the code locks in the while loop because there is a bug into this line `var end = start.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-start.Day);`.
Month 05 (May) have 31 days but month 06 (June) have 30 days, so in this rhis situation the code adds a month (30 days because June has 30 days) and substracts 31 days, resulting into an error. The fix is replace the buggy code with:
var end = start.AddMonths(1);
end = end.AddDays(-end.Day);

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is for you to convert everything into days first.

eg. `x= 361 ; // total number of days`

then from there you can split them up into months and years .

```
months = x/30; // find months 
days = x%30; // find the remainder of the days from the month
years = months/12; // find years
```

This way its much easier to calculate.

Comment: What about `2017/01/31` - `2017/03/01`?

Comment: firstly. my method is to find the number of dates in that given range 2017/01/31 - 2017/03/01 this equates to 89 days. then from there you devide by 30 to find the month = 2. from there you can see that it is 0 years 2 month and 29 days.

Comment: Wrong. That date range represents 30 days spread over _3_ months. February in 2017 had only 28 days and picking the last day of January and the first day of March makes 30 days. Your method is incorrect for a number of reasons.

Comment: Don't fit _my_ criteria - just make sure you perform correct date calculations. You cannot assume months have 30 days and depending on the year, you cannot assume that a year is 365 days long.